# Concatenate many rows into a single text string with group

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with two columns like

```
VENDOR_NAME   DIRECTORY_NAME
DL_101Records  .ssh
DL_101Records  ADHOC
DL_101Records  ARCHIVED
DL_101Records  INBOUND
DL_101Records  OUTBOUND
DL_101Records  PROCESSED
DL_101Records  pub
DL_101Records  TAKEDOW
```

N

Is there an easy way to turn this into a single string like

```
VENDOR_NAME    DIRECTORY_NAME
DL_101Records  .SSH ,ADHOC ,ARCHIVED ,INBOUND ,OUTBOUND ,PROCESSED ,PUB ,TAKEDOWN
```

Comment: visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT VENDOR_NAME,
       DIRECTORY_NAME = STUFF(
                             (
                                 SELECT ', '+DIRECTORY_NAME AS [text()]
                                 FROM _table AS t
                                 WHERE t.VENDOR_NAME = tt.VENDOR_NAME
                                 ORDER BY t.DIRECTORY_NAME
                                 FOR XML PATH('')
                             ), 1, 2, '')
FROM _table tt
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME;
```

Comment: -Thank You. it worked

Comment: How can i get the DIRECTORY_NAME in Order clause?

Comment: @MidhunCM `ORDER BY` added

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
DECLARE @TEMP VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @TEMP=@TEMP+DIRECTORY_NAME+', ' FROM YOURTABLE
SELECT VENDOR_NAME,@TEMP FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME
```